# Communication through GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) between two different apps

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have two Apps C and D. What I want to achieve is send a notification from C (which is on one device ) to D (which is on a different device) through GCM. And when the user clicks on the notification that is received for app D, an Activity inside D starts. I don't know if I can do this or not. I am able to send and receive notification within an app installed on different device  s but communicating between different apps seems to me a bit tricky. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your question is nice but it's tricky.

Comment: Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Yup but first u need to implement `GCM` then we'll work on this stuff.

Comment: I have already done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You van do this the following way:

The two apps can either use the same sender ID or a different one. If they use a different sender ID, your server will need a different API Key for each sender ID. There is no reason for the two apps to have the same package name.

Your server will accept registration IDs from both apps. You'll have to store each registration ID with a field that indicates to which application it belongs to.

If app C on one device wants to send a GCM message to app D on another device, it will send a message to the server (indicating somehow the identifier of the recipient device and application - it's up to you to decide how to identify the recipient). Then the server will find the registration ID of the recipient device for app D and use the API key matching this app to send the message to that device.

Comment: Just let me know If I will have to add some permissions in the receiving app (D in this case).

Comment: @Puneetr90 You don't need any special permissions. You need the regular permissions required by any application that uses GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use same Sender ID for both apps. But when you send a message, you specify a registration ID, which is implicitly linked to the package name of the app + device where it was generated. Only the app which requested the registration ID will receive your message. Finally, You have to put same package name for both app.

Note : You can't install two apps on Android device which have same package name.

Edit based on Comment :

You can do this if you know about package name of another app. Say, It would be:

```
    com.example.myappD
```

Now, Use Intent and and launch default launcher activity:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.myappD");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

In launcher activity `onCreate()` just check from where you are navigating to this activity. And launch your required activity if you coming from notification.

Comment: Thanks Manish. I have already done that. but the thing is how to  pass the pending intent(that is opened when the user clicks the notifictaion) as the activity from the different app.

Comment: Also I think, I will have to specify some permission in the manifest file of the receiving app to let it get notification from different app. pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: can you tell me what permission do I need to provide. I am confused like hell :P